# Can not fetch /sqlite-autoconf-3080703

Tags: sqlite

I got this when I tried install apsw:

```
running fetch
  Getting the SQLite amalgamation
    **Fetching https://sqlite.org/2014/sqlite-autoconf-3080703.tar.gz
       Error  <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network i**s unreachable>
        Try # 2
       Error  <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
        Try # 3
       Error  <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
        Try # 4
       Error  <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
        Try # 5
       Error  <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
error: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
```

Looks like https://www.sqlite.org/ is down.

Has any of you encounter the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is question for StackOverflow. But if you'd ask, how to get this information, I would recommend services like:

https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/www.sqlite3.org

http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/sqlite3.org.html

https://down.com/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sqlite3.org

Two of them already found out, that it is down.